# How to Close Scaffold Drawer programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to close my drawer from outside of the Scaffold widget progmatically. I opened the drawer using `_scaffoldkey.currentState.openDrawer`.

Is there is any similar way to close the drawer?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use `Navigator.pop`. The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openDrawer.html) also states this:

> To close the drawer once it is open, use [Navigator.pop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html).

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: This can also make the app exit if drawer isn't opened. Not a good appraoch.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

---

If you are willing to close the drawer on back button press, you can use

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    bool isDrawerOpen = _scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen;
    if (isDrawerOpen) {
      Navigator.pop(context); // close the drawer
      return Future.value(false); // don't allow app to navigate back
    } else {
      return Future.value(true); // allow app to navigate back
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(...),
);
```